# How do I get entry bar to stick to the bottom of div container?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to get the entry bar to stay at the bottom of the div container but I am at a loss at how to do so. Any help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './NameBox';

class ChatBox extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="chat-box-container">
                    <div className="chat-box">
                        <h1>Chat Room</h1>
                        <div style={{/*GET THIS TO STICK TO BOTTOM OF THE DIV ABOVE*/}}>
                            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
                                <div className="input-group-append">
                                    <a href="/chat" onClick={this.getName} className="btn btn-success" type="button">Enter</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>{localStorage.getItem("username")} has entered the chat...</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ChatBox;
```

Comment: you asking us how can ı stick but where is your css ? :)

Answer (score 1):

I know your code is in React and JSX but just as a general answer. To position something relative to a div you need to give the parent div `position: relative` and then for the entry bar you can do `position: absolute` alongside `bottom: 0` to position the entry bar at the bottom.

```html
<div style="
    position: relative; 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;"
>
    <input type="text" 
        style="
           position: absolute;
           bottom: 0;"
        placeholder="Entry Bar"
    />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my css:)

```
.name-box-container {
  margin: auto;
}

.name-box {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 600px;
  margin-right: 600px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.entry-bar-container {
  margin: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.chat-box-container {
  margin: auto;
}

.chat-box {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 450px;
  margin-right: 450px;
  height: 630px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```